# Are any modifications to the FHS being worked on (by the Linux Foundation)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fhs, standard

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/227625/386242 explains the myriad benefits of a simpler and more consistent filesystem hierarchy, but also that without any cross-OS standardization, such efforts are as much of a disadvantage as they are an advantage.

Consequently, is the Linux Foundation drafting a Filesystem Hierarchy Standard 3.1 or 4.0?

Comment: How about you ask the Linux Foundation, lol.

Comment: Have you even read the FHS? FHS is highly consistent in achieving its goals. Your linked sugestions just shows that other people don't understand the idea behind FHS too. Throwing everything into one directory is something that even Windows doesn't do anymore.

Comment: @paladin, I don't know what you're referring to. I read nothing which would indicate a desire to place most files within a singular directory - that would necessitate significantly better XDG Extended Attribute (tag) support, as well as make that singular directory fairly redundant.

Comment: Distributions are moving to a single /lib directory, so you may see there is something going on, but on consensus. I think there is no need to do in the LHF manner. But I think there is a need to update it to reflect the actual use, and to address few bugs/missing information. OTOH most of the discussion linked is not useful. We have package managers, and we see which package has which file. And this structure is much more efficient to parse (no long parsing paths like in Windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the lack of activity [on the mailing list that would be used to discuss revisions to the standard](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/fhs-discuss/), I think it’s safe to say the answer is no.

Even if a group was working on a revised standard, the standard is supposed to reflect consensus, so I suspect you’d have a hard time getting it updated to follow GoboLinux-style practices.